# R - How to continue iteration when nrow < N

Tags: r, list, for-loop, iteration

I'm using the TTR package to calculate exponential moving averages on a large list of data frames.  When I try the for loop below I get an evaluation error if I set n>1.

```
options(digits = 3)
for(i in seq_along(list)){
    list[[i]] <- list[[i]] %>%
    mutate(exp.ma = EMA(x, n = 10))
}
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: n = 10 is outside valid range: [1, 7].

When setting n = 2  :

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: n = 2 is outside valid range: [1, 1].

Interestingly, I can run the code successfully if I set `n = nrow(list[[i]])` however this handicaps my ability to specify any other `n` value - it's either `n = 1` or `n = nrow(list)`.

This is puzzling me because I have no issues running the same for loop using the `rollmean` function, regardless of the number of periods (k).  Also, I have no issues running the same function on a single data frame:

`df <- df %>% mutate(exp.ma = EMA(x, n = 10))`

It seems to me that this error has something to do with successfully/unsuccessfully iterating `i` over the length of the list.  I'm sure my code is not the most efficient way of approaching this problem so any guidance is appreciated.

**EDIT: reproducible example**

```
library(TTR)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

# reproducible example
set.seed(1363)
d1 <- data.frame(val1 = c(rnorm(n=3, mean=15)), val2 = c(rnorm(n=3, mean=15)))
d2 <- data.frame(val1 = c(rnorm(n=35, mean=12)), val2 = c(rnorm(n=35, mean=25)))

my.list <- list(df1 = d1, df2 = d2)

for (i in seq_along(my.list)) {
  my.list[[i]] <- my.list[[i]] %>%
   mutate(exp.ma = EMA(val2, n = 5))
}
> Error in EMA(val2, n = 5) : n = 5 is outside valid range: [1, 3]
```

I figured out what was causing the error.  The first data frame in the list (d1) has 3 rows therefore setting n=5 will produce the `n=5 is outside valid range: [1, 3]` The first clue should've been the fact that the for loop worked when I set `n=nrow(list[[i]])`

My question now is how can I set the for loop so that it doesn't stop when it loops over a data frame with `nrows < n` or better yet, it calculates the first available EMA value based on the number of rows in a data frame.

Comment: Hi. Can you please tag your question with the programming language? You will be sure to get a better audience that way. I can't tell what language it is. Looks like Python maybe?

Comment: In my haste to post I forgot to include R in the title and tag it accordingly.  Thank you for catching that, Kodos.

Comment: try changing assignment operator to "=" here in ```list[[i]] <- list[[i]] ``` i.e. use ```list[[i]] = list[[i]] ```

Comment: @AkarshJain: using `=` gave me the same error.

Comment: @On_an_island Give reproducible toy example to produce the same error.

Comment: @AkarshJain, thank you for your interest in helping out.  The issue had to do with the fact that the data frames in my list have different row lengths.  Unfortunately, this causes the `TTR::EMA` function to produce an error instead of continuing the loop and outputting an NA value like `rollmean` function does.  Now I'm on to a new issue as you will see based on my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the number with a choice of the smallest of either the number or the number of rows, e.g.:

```
mutate(exp.ma = EMA(val2, n = min(c(5,length(val2)))))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!  Will make sure to +1 once I have enough reputation points.